# Scanning a file sends the function into unresponsive mode?

Tags: c, file

So, I was writing a function to validate a CNIC number and I wanted it to read a file to make sure it doesn't already exist, however the issue is that instead of checking the file, once I enter the  cnic, it just goes unresponsive, instead of giving the prompt to reenter the cnic
Here's the relevant function:

```
   void ValidCNIC() {
    check:  ;
            FILE *comp;
            int i = 0, check = 0;
            rec DupliCh;
            char ch;
            printf("Now enter the cnic (it must only be 13 numbers long):\n");
            fgets(AddRec.cnic,sizeof(AddRec.cnic),stdin);
            fflush(stdin);
            while(i < strlen(AddRec.cnic)-1) {
                    ch = AddRec.cnic[i];
                    if((ch >= 48 && ch <= 57) ) {
                            i++;
                    }
                    else{
                            printf("The cnic can contain numbers only!\n");
                            printf("Press 1 to retry:\n");
                            scanf("%d",&check);
                            if(check==1) {
                                    fflush(stdin);
                                    goto check;
                            }
                    }
            }
            if (strnlen(AddRec.cnic,sizeof(AddRec.cnic)) < 14)
            {
                    printf("The number is too short\nPlz reenter\n");
                    fordelay(1000000000);
                    goto check;
            }
            else if (strnlen(AddRec.cnic,sizeof(AddRec.cnic)) > 14) {
                    printf("The number is too long\nPlz reenter\n");
                    fordelay(1000000000);
                    goto check;
            }
            AddRec.cnic[strnlen(AddRec.cnic,sizeof(AddRec.cnic))-1] = '\0';
            do{
                    comp = fopen("Records.txt","r");
                    fscanf(comp,"(%s) %lli %s %s %d/%d/%d (%s) %f ",&DupliCh.name, &DupliCh.AccNum, &DupliCh.AccTyp, &DupliCh.cnic, &DupliCh.dob.day, &DupliCh.dob.month, &DupliCh.dob.year, &DupliCh.addr, &DupliCh.available_balance);
                    if(DupliCh.cnic == AddRec.cnic) {
                            printf("uh huh a person with this cnic already has an account\nYou sure you're not trying to commit identity fraud!?\n please try again!!!!!\n");
                            fordelay(1000000000);
                            ValidCNIC();
                    }
            }
            while (feof(comp) != EOF);
    }
```

This is the structure being referred to here:

```
    typedef struct date {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
} date;

typedef struct record {
        long long int AccNum;
        char name[100];
        char cnic[50];
        date dob;
        char addr[150];
        char AccTyp[50];
        float available_balance;
} rec;

rec AddRec;
```

Comment: You have not shown us the definition for `AddRec`

Comment: oh I'll add it rn

Comment: I can see two things straight off - 1. you reopen `comp` on each iteration of the `do...while`, hence it is an eternal loop (also leaking resources). 2. your string comparison in the `do...while` is wrong for c, use `strncmp`.

Comment: It will loop forever if you have a non-numeric character and check is not 1.  Note that fgets includes the newline.

Comment: @fredrik I tried doing both, it still doesn't work, and  gets unresponsive

Comment: The C standard makes `fflush(stdin);` *Undefined Behavior* on all but *"seekable"* streams. There is one non-standard implementation that allows its use on `stdin`. If you mean `'0'` use `'0'` (not `48`) and if your mean `'9'` use `'9'` (not `57`), it will be much more readable.

Comment: `comp = fopen("Records.txt","r");` should NOT be inside the loop unless there is a `fclose(comp);` at the end. Get rid of the `space` at the end of `"(%s) %lli %s %s %d/%d/%d (%s) %f "` (it will never match), you must VALIDATE the input with `if (fscanf(comp,"(%s) %lli %s %s %d/%d/%d (%s) %f", ...) = 9) { /* then good input */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cup pointed out, you need to consider the fact that a newline could (and usually will) be at the end of your string. I see you set the last character of the string to `'\0'`, but only after the loop is done, and your loop will get stuck because newline is NOT between 48 and 57. (BTW, you can use `isdigit` for that, and it will make your code clearer.) Perhaps your better solution is to use `scanf` instead of `fgets`, as in:

```
if (scanf(" %13[0-9] ",AddRec.cnic) != 1) {
    puts("Try again");
    fflush(stdin);
    goto check;
}
if (strlen(AddRec.cnic) != 13) {
    puts("Error: You must enter exactly 13 numeric digits!");
    fflush(stdin);
    goto check;
}
```

Note that using `scanf` avoids the need to deal with the newline character. BTW, you should avoid `goto`'s unless absolutely necessary, and you could avoid them here by using a `do`...`while` with an `okay` semaphore.

Comment: These are good suggestions, I'll implement them thanks! Anyways could you explain what you mean by a semaphore, we haven't encountered them in our course so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: A semaphore is just a flag used to test a condition, either in a loop or a thread. In this case you could declare `bool okay = FALSE;`, and then create an outer loop in your code `do {` ... `} while (!okay);`, and then set `okay` to `TRUE` when you get a valid input. Thay way the loop repeats until you get a valid input.